# Can't sort dates with PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
$dates = array();
$dates['01-07-2013'] = 'dummy data';
$dates['01-21-2013'] = 'dummy data';
$dates['01-28-2013'] = 'dummy data';
$dates['01-20-2012'] = 'dummy data';
```

When using **ksort($dates)** it's not sorting them correctly.  Is there a way to sort keys like this?

I would expect the sort to return:

```
'01-30-2012',
'01-07-2013',
'01-21-2013',
'01-28-2013',
```

Comment: Did you try with the `flag SORT_STRING`? Like `ksort($dates, SORT_STRING);`

Answer (score 9):

Those aren't dates, as far as PHP is concerned. They're strings, so it's applying standard string sorting rules to it.

You'll need to define a custom sort function for use with `usort()`, or convert those dates to a format that IS sortable as a string, e.g.

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array();
$dates[time()] = 'dummy data';
```

Converting to unix timestamp may help as it is just a number (integer) that can be sorted easily.

Answer (score 0):

[ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) defaults sort type to `SORT_REGULAR`

> SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)

and the format of your dates will evaluate in PHP to generic String.

You need these to be formatted so that sorting them as a string would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can us uksort but in the comparison function look like this:

```
function sort_func($date1, $date2){
    return strtotime(str_replace("-","/", $date1)) - strtotime(str_replace("-","/", $date2));
}

uksort($dates, "sort_func");
```